# Composer не запускается из консоли

Tags: composer, openserver

Установлен OpenServer. В переменные среды добавлен путь к исполняемому файлу PHP требуемой версии D:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\  Из командной строки cmd -> C:\Users\Alex>composer -V пишет: """" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

открываешь консоль в openserver-е(флаг в панеле задач -> пр.кн -> дополнительно. 
у тебя будет путь корневой папки openserver-a, командой cd modules\php\PHP-5.6 переходишь в папку пхп. далее командой php composer.phar self-update обновляешь композ и вуаля.

Comment: Krafik,
> открываешь консоль в openserver-е А нельзя ли открыть консоль сразу в папке с php?

Comment: не сработало, проблема осталась

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в использовании Open Server, в котором уже установлен Composer. Зайдите в `\OpenServer\modules\php\`, выберите версию PHP, которую вы используете, и удалите файлы `composer.bat` и `composer.phar`. После перезагрузки сервера команда `composer` сразу заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Так как установлен Open Server, то PHP установленны в каталоге Open Server, и при установке Open Server вы указали путь к PHP? который установлен в Open Server. Надо просто в пременных средах Windows, в path создать переменную указав путь к PHP который установлен в Open Server и вуаля, теперь composer видит и командная строка Windows